# Are parameters needed for inner functions to access props + variables of a React Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I have a functional component that has a couple of functions inside of it. In the example below, the inner functions are `function1` and `function2`. I am trying to figure out if i need to explicitly pass the functional component's props (`prop1`, `prop2`), as well as other declared variables within the functional component (`variable1`, `variable2`) into these inner functions. Here is an example:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3';

function MyFunction({prop1, prop2}) {
    const variable1 = '#333333';
    const variable2 = 'Jimmy';

    const function1 = () => {
        d3.select('g.g1')
            .append('rect')
            .attr('color', variable1)
    }

    const function2 = () => {
        d3.select('g.g2')
            .append('text')
            .text(prop1.label)
    }

    return (
        <svg>
            <g className='g1' />
            <g className='g2' />
        </svg>
    );
}

export default MyFunction;
```

It seems to simplify my code if I don't have to explicitly declare parameters for function1 and function2 to be able to use these props + other variables declared in the upper scope, however I am not sure if this is a bad practice, or if this will cause other issues with my code. Is this okay?

### Edit

Wanted to note that this does, in fact, seem to work without any issues. My question is more a matter of - should I do this / is it okay / are there problems I may run into down the road doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a function in a function is perfectly fine. There are all kinds of articles you can read on if you should use `useCallback`. I'll talk about that in a second.

No, you don't need to pass the props to each function. The reason for this is closures and what it captures. [Here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/get-started/ch3.md) is some reading on it under closures. Your arrow function closes over the props variable if they reference it. So nope, you don't need to pass it, and check out that link. And Chapter 2 if you really want to dig in depth.

As for performance, it's normally fine! Every time your component renders though, `function1` and `function2` will be redefined. They'll be the same exact function (unless `d3` changes), but with a different reference, so the old `function1` !== the new `function1` even if they do the same thing. This is why that matters...

For a little more overhead though (per render of the component, possibly saving many renders of other components or `useEffect` executions), you can have react analyze if it should redefine `function1` or `function2` and if not, it keeps the same reference. This is what `useCallback` does. Honestly, I use `useCallback` if I'm ever unsure if the function will cause me issues. An example is when a child component has `function1` passed in as a prop. That prop will ALWAYS be evaluated as a new value on every render of the parent because it's a new reference, unless you use `useCallback`.

Comment: It was previously suggested to me to dig deep into closures, especially as I refactor my app from class components to hooks, and so I will check out the shared link.

Appreciate the input. I'll definitely look into useCallback as well. Some of the larger functional components of mine are large-ish in size (500 - 1K lines of code), with multiple (5 - 10) inner-functions. I haven't had performance issues before but I will keep an eye on it.

Comment: If they are a dependency of anything, I'd use `useCallback`. Otherwise, not a big deal. If they just evaluate a value, check out `useMemo`. Sometimes `useMemo` can substitute for a `useEffect` + `useState`

Comment: They take in arrays of data, and create graphs and other data viz using D3. I have a `useEffect` that handles re-drawing the graphs when the props (the arrays of data) change.

Comment: if that `useEffect` uses any of your functions... those functions need to use `useCallback`. Or `useEffect` will run every time. Assuming you are following best practices with your dependency array.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the input on this, super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

first of all this approach of having function inside a function is not recommended , it proves performance expenseive very often and yes if you have to use you need to pass the props into them. Also see this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57685732/declaring-function-inside-function-in-react)

Comment: Thanks. I'll think about splitting the inner functions into their own components. However, you mention `and yes if you have to use you need to pass the props into them`, but this is not the case. It's not required. See the edit to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You do want to pass the props as explicit arguments. As long as you don't pass any props that you're not using (`prop2` above, for example), your code will not be simpler from omitting them. Especially as your use cases for them grows, along with the functions that need them, this will actually prevent verbose code.

But, as you found yourself, it is not required for a working component. The react docs show this throughout all of their examples. For ex - visit this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#extracting-components).

Comment: How would it make my code more or less simple from omitting / excluding these props / variables as parameters to the inner functions? There would literally be no difference, besides the function parameters being declared vs. not declared.

Comment: you wouldn't have to write `props.prop_name` every time you passed the prop through to  a function

Comment: I am already destructuring the props in the functional component's very first line `function MyFunction({prop1, prop2})`, so i don't have to write `props.` ever.

Comment: Misread the question!! Thought you were asking whether or not to pass the props in the outer scope. An argument for passing the props to the inner functions as well is reusability - often you might pass a function as a prop to another component. For ex., a clickHandler that you should only run on a top-level where you have access to important data. If you use `prop1.label` instead of giving an argument, other components will not be able to call this function correctly. I see that's not what you have here, but it's an ex. of how passing the props provides functions with more versatility.